# Julia - How to index vector w/ vector of vector of indices?

Tags: indexing, julia, vectorization

Suppose `idxs` is a vector of vectors defined as

```
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [1, 4]
```

And suppose `A` is a vector defined as

```
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

With Python and numpy, I could simply do (in pseudocode) `A[idxs]` and this would return a 2-D array containing the elements

```
[
  [6 7]
  [6 8]
  [6 9]
]
```

How do I perform the same indexing in Julia, where I am indexing multiple times into a 1-dimensional vector, and retrieving a matrix of entries?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a 2D Array or a 1D Vector as result?

Comment: 2D Array (Matrix, not a vector of vectors). Interestingly, when using @DecowVR answer, I'm running into some weird results where summing along the rows of the output isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array comprehension with `hcat`. You can either use the resulting 2x3 Matrix or transpose the result.

```
julia> hcat([A[i] for i in id]...)'
3×2 adjoint(::Matrix{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
 6  7
 6  8
 6  9
```

##### Data

```
julia> show(id)
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]

julia> show(A)
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to use list comprehension

```
julia> [A[i] for i in idxs]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [6, 7]
 [6, 8]
 [6, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers, which are good, I will note that if you can rearrange your starting indices to be a proper 2D array, rather than a vector of vectors (either along the lines of the following or by filling them into a 2D array to start with)

```
julia> idxs = vcat(transpose.(idxs)...)
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 1  3
 1  4
```

then you can do this by simply directly indexing `A` with the 2D array of `idxs`:

```
julia> idxs
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 1  3
 1  4

julia> A[idxs]
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 6  7
 6  8
 6  9
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the underlying function behind `A[i]`, that is `getindex(A,i)`. you could broadcast that function and obtain what you want:

```
A = collect(6:10),idxs = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]];
res = getindex.(Ref(A),idxs)
```

the `Ref(A)` is to make a "constant" element during broadcasting (broadcasting applies functions for each element of a collection with shapes, but A and idxs doesnt have the same shape. `Ref(A)` fixes that by behaving like an scalar)